No terminals launch on Ubuntu 22.04
I got an unmanaged VPS from Hostinger a week ago and accessed it via mRemoteNG RDP. I find a few terminals installed including gnome, but none of them work. Every attempt to start a terminal ends with it crashing.
I just wanted to install a Windows program after having installed Wine. I am also hosting a few web sites on the server and some are still propagating.
I have to say here that I am quite new to Ubuntu. I set the gnome-terminal emulator as the default one and made some attempts via Hostinger browser terminal to get it running without success:

sudo nano /usr/bin/gnome-terminal and replaced #!/usr/bin/python3 with #!/usr/bin/python3.10.
sudo apt install dconf-editor
sudo locale-gen --purge
sudo apt remove gnome-terminal
sudo apt install gnome-terminal
I installed the web browser Chrome on the server, downloaded mt5setup.exe and tried to run it with Wine Windows Program Loader. The cursor showed loading and then it disappeared.

The only thing I may have done wrong was running
wget https://download.mql5.com/cdn/web/metaquotes.software.corp/mt5/mt5ubuntu.sh chmod +x mt5ubuntu.sh ./mt5ubuntu.sh
from the Hostinger browser terminal to install MetaTrader 5, a Windows program. According to the instructions, I should have run it on a terminal after accessing the server via RDP. I deleted the following files later:
/root/mt5setup.exe
/root/mt5setup.exe.1
/root/mt5ubuntu.sh
/root/mt5ubuntu.sh.1
Please help me solve this problem.
